# Finding out which Hosting Provider they are with?

Tags: ip, whois

From a domain or IP, how to find out which Hosting Provider they have signed up with?

I did whois on IP and it said it come from net2ez.com but I like to find out which third party Web Hosting (or Dedicated/VPS Hosting) they are with..

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to tell. The only thing you can find out (as you already mentioned) is who the maintainer of the IP block is, by running a `whois` on the IP. There is no way to tell where it goes from there. There could be a dedicated server behind that IP (client A). They can have hosting packages sold to their clients (Client B). But client B might also be a reseller and have client C who is the actual end-user.

There's no way to trace who all the contractors are, that's an administrative thing and is technically untracable. All you can see it the provider that provides/maintains the IP address.

Although the somewhat larger hosting providers/resellers usually have their own PI space with the original maintainer and thus the whois will show their name.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/458527/redstation-com-is-heaven-for-ddos-attackers-how-to-file-complaint/458529#458529